# My video is playing upside down

Tags: ffmpeg

I took photos and recorded video of a family wedding as a surprise. I edited all images and loaded them on a flash drive along with the video so she can view them on the TV. When plugged into TV to make sure all works and plays correctly, three of the videos are fine but a 25 minute video of the service is upside down. This same video plays right-side up on my PC.

I have read the previous replies here and understand what the cause is and what needs to be done, however I find it difficult to understand HOW do that.

My first question would be is it the master build of ffmpeg I need to download for windows as in the screen shot, and would anyone be so kind as to give me a step by step walkthrough on converting the video, or is the program self explanatory?

Worst case is she can still watch the video on her laptop but if possible i`d like to get it on the USB drive.

[image: screen shot]

Comment: the top one in your screenshot should be fine: "ffmpeg-git-essentials.7z". Extract it to a folder, then you'll have `/foldername/bin/ffmpeg.exe`. It might be a bit easier to do in something with an interface though: https://www.howtogeek.com/14751/rotate-a-video-on-windows/

Comment: Hello, this question is a mess. You should only ask one question per one post and it should focus around a specific problem. I recommend reading https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Hello, thank you kindly for the info and reminding me. As you can see it was already answered. However, having had three heart attacks I am not sure if you are aware but part of the the old brain dies off. The best way of describing the after effects is like formatting a hard drive, a bit like my post really, my head is a complete mess. Oh well shall not have to put up with it for too long, I reckon going by the laws of averages I only have about 20yrs if that on this planet.